# ACCES:insert select with an iterate where condition

Tags: sql, select, loops, insert

I'm quite new of Access and vba and SQl but still  I need to use these all together.
What I have to do is duplicate some record on certain table basing on a set of  criteria;
In order to do this I've managed to perform an "insert select" statement.
In brief my problem is that I've have to duplicate N times the same record where some field values in the table  is equal to a certain value.
here is my code : this allows me to iterate the sql statements N times (Where N is taken from a Table )

```
    Sub trydup()
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim asd As DAO.Recordset
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("piv")
With rst
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 36
Dim NOM(1 To 36) As String
Dim NUM(1 To 36)
NOM(i) = !CDPRD
NUM(i) = !n
.MoveNext
Next
End With
Set asd = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Acc6")
MsgBox (NUM(4) & "   " & NOM(4))
With asd
Dim k As Integer
Dim n As Long
For n = 1 To 36
Do While k <= NUM(n)
  CurrentDb.Execute " INSERT into Acc6 SELECT * from Acc6 where CD_MAD = " & "'NOM(" & n & " )'"
k = k + 1
Loop
Next n
End With
End Sub
```

indeed if i run instead this code:

```
Sub trydup()
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim asd As DAO.Recordset
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("piv")
With rst
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 36
Dim NOM(1 To 36) As String
Dim NUM(1 To 36)
NOM(i) = !CDPRD
NUM(i) = !n
.MoveNext
Next
End With
Set asd = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Acc6")
MsgBox (NUM(4) & "   " & NOM(4))
With asd
Dim k As Integer
Dim n As Long
For n = 1 To 36
Do While k <= NUM(n)
  *CurrentDb.Execute " INSERT into Acc6 SELECT * from Acc6 where CD_MAD='PCA' " )'"*
k = k + 1
Loop
Next n
End With
End Sub
```

where PCA is the value containde in the vector NOM the vba works fine!
so the question is how to extract in sql statement all the values of the vector "NOM" iterativley?
thak you in advance for the answares!!!!

I Have an update on the issue.
Let's consider a little bit more easier problem:
Assume that i want to do the same thing for just one step in my code:
the first value in the NUM vector is = 12
in the NOM = PCA
so what basically i'd like to do is to look for all the rows in my table that have the field value CD_MAD='PCA' and then copy 12 time this record in the same table! so my code will be something like this:

```
    Sub trydup()
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim asd As DAO.Recordset
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("piv")
With rst
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 36
Dim NOM(1 To 36) As String
Dim NUM(1 To 36)
NOM(i) = !CDPRD
NUM(i) = !n
.MoveNext
Next
End With
Set asd = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Acc6")
   With asd
   Dim n As Long
For n = 1 To 36
Do While k <= 12
  CurrentDb.Execute " INSERT into Acc6 SELECT * from Acc6 where CD_MAD='PCA' " )'"
k = k + 1
Loop
End With
End Sub
```

the problem here is basically in the "where criteria":
indeed assuming that at the step 0 in my source table  there are 4 records that verify the criteria CD_MAD='PCA'
at the second step there will 8 , at 3 step there will be 16 and so on... that's not what i'd like to obtain since i'd like to replies that particular raw just 12 times!!!
what i'd like to do is to find a way to perform one time the select istruction and than insert that selection 12 times!!!!
help my  please I'm going slightly Mad!!

---

I Have an update on the issue.
Let's consider a little bit more easier problem:
Assume that i want to do the same thing for just one step in my code:
the first value in the NUM vector is = 12
in the NOM = PCA
so what basically i'd like to do is to look for all the rows in my table that have the field value CD_MAD='PCA' and then copy 12 time this record in the same table! so my code will be something like this:

```
    Sub trydup()
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim asd As DAO.Recordset
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("piv")
With rst
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 36
Dim NOM(1 To 36) As String
Dim NUM(1 To 36)
NOM(i) = !CDPRD
NUM(i) = !n
.MoveNext
Next
End With
Set asd = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Acc6")
   With asd
   Dim n As Long
For n = 1 To 36
Do While k <= 12
  CurrentDb.Execute " INSERT into Acc6 SELECT * from Acc6 where CD_MAD='PCA' " )'"
k = k + 1
Loop
End With
End Sub
```

the problem here is basically in the "where criteria":
indeed assuming that at the step 0 in my source table  there are 4 records that verify the criteria CD_MAD='PCA'
at the second step there will 8 , at 3 step there will be 16 and so on... that's not what i'd like to obtain since i'd like to replies that particular raw just 12 times!!!
what i'd like to do is to find a way to perform one time the select istruction and than insert that selection 12 times!!!!
help my  please I'm going slightly Mad!!

Answer (score 0):

This `"...where CD_MAD  & "'NOM(" & n & " )'"` doesn't do what you want it to. Since the SQL string makes a reference to an Array it doesn't have access to.

Change it to this which will extract the value from `NOM` and then concatenate the value to the string

```
" ... where CD_MAD = '" & NOM(n) & "'"
```

Comment: edit: there is a runtime error!!!!  cannot open database INSERT into Acc6 SELECT * from Acc6 where CD_MAD='PCA' it may not be a databes that your application recognise or the file may be corrupted!

Comment: hmm that's weird. That happens on `CurrentDB.Execute " INSERT`

Comment: Sorry I meant my previous comment to be a question. Does this happen to you on the line `CurrentDb.Execute " INSERT ...`?

Comment: unfortunatly that code had distroyed all my database! I've lost all my sourcecode, I'm tryng to reach again that step in my database!, when I'll reach that scope 'll let you know again!

Comment: ok i've restored all my work, and yes the error is in the currentDb.execute line!!!!1 what sould I do???

Comment: the results is that there are 20000 repetioton of the first Nom insetad of just 12!!!!!

Comment: I've came to understand what the proble is: actually NUM(n) express the total Number of duplication per line!!! but this code has a big problem: the query criteria is not fixed, the selected raws auments with the number of the k iteration generating at the end a number of replys that is so much bigger than what i've expected!!!! Now I've to find a way to solve this problem!!!